# Kotlin Channel doesn't finish

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am quite new to Kotlin `Channel`.

So below code is practice code for the `produce` extension function which returns a `ReceiveChannel`. For every iteration by `repeat(10)`, the variable `cur` is reassigned with a new `ReceiveChannel`. That's why I am invoking the `cancel()` method inside the `filter` extension function.

I was expecting for this to finish normally, but it doesn't:

```
fun CoroutineScope.numbersFrom(start: Int) = produce<Int> {
    var x = start
    while (true) send(x++) // infite stream of integers from start
}

fun CoroutineScope.filter(numbers: ReceiveChannel<Int>, prime: Int) = produce<Int> {
    for (x in numbers) if (x % prime != 0) send(x)
    numbers.cancel() // Canceled here
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        var cur = numbersFrom(2) // infinitely send numbers...
        repeat(10) {
            val prime = cur.receive() // retrieve only one element
            println(prime)
            cur = filter(cur, prime) // new Receiver
        }
        cur.cancel() // Canceled here
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: BlockingCoroutine was cancelled; job=BlockingCoroutine{Cancelled}@26a7b76d

```
fun CoroutineScope.numbersFrom(start: Int) = produce<Int> {
    var x = start
    while (true) send(x++) // infite stream of integers from start
}

fun CoroutineScope.filter(numbers: ReceiveChannel<Int>, prime: Int) = produce<Int> {
    for (x in numbers) if (x % prime != 0) send(x)
    numbers.cancel()
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        var cur = numbersFrom(2) // infinitely send numbers...
        repeat(10) {
            val prime = cur.receive() // retrieve only one element
            println(prime)
            cur = filter(cur, prime) // new Receiver
        }
        cur.cancel()
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }
}
```

Also, this code ends naturally, as it cancels all childeren coroutine:

```
fun CoroutineScope.numbersFrom(start: Int) = produce<Int> {
    var x = start
    while (true) send(x++) // infite stream of integers from start
}

fun CoroutineScope.filter(numbers: ReceiveChannel<Int>, prime: Int) = produce<Int> {
    for (x in numbers) if (x % prime != 0) send(x)
    numbers.cancel()
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        var cur = numbersFrom(2) // infinitely send numbers...
        repeat(10) {
            val prime = cur.receive() // retrieve only one element
            println(prime)
            cur = filter(cur, prime) // new Receiver
        }
        coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can make it finish naturally without using `coroutineContext.cancelChildren()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `filter` method.

You loop over all numbers and *then* cancel the numbers channel.
As the numbers channel creates an *unlimited* series of numbers, the loop will never end and the next line in your code, the point where the channel is cancelled, can never be reached.

I do not really understand what you try to achieve with your code, so I cannot suggest a concrete solution - other than putting the call to `cancel()` somewhere else, where it will actually be executed.

Comment: You were right. I couldn't print anything after loop in filter method since the code never reaches after loop.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't make this kind of code at the first place Thank you!